# KSQL - Change the time zone in WINDOW TUMBLING clause

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Here my KSQL using `WINDOW TUMBLING` clause:

```
SELECT 
    sale_date,
    region,
    SUM(total)
FROM orders
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 24 HOURS)
GROUP BY sale_date, region;
```

Some result:

```
2018-09-29|+|zskx_fz : Window{start=1538179200000 end=-} | 2018-09-29 | zskx_fz | 16119.8
2018-09-30|+|zskx_fz : Window{start=1538179200000 end=-} | 2018-09-30 | zskx_fz | 2031.6
2018-09-30|+|zskx_fz : Window{start=1538265600000 end=-} | 2018-09-30 | zskx_fz | 894.7
```

And the epoch millis to date time is:

```
1538179200000 = 2018-09-29 08:00:00 (UTC+8)
1538265600000 = 2018-09-30 08:00:00 (UTC+8)
```

As we can see, I'm in UTC+8. But regardless the time zone, `start` date time should be `2018-09-29 00:00:00` not 8 hours earlier. So it's able to change the time zone?

PS: I tried out several window size at `2018-09-30 11:33:00` and I totally lost..

```
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 minutes)    2018-09-30 11:32:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 2 hours)      2018-09-30 10:00:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 5 hours)      2018-09-30 07:00:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 10 hours)     2018-09-30 02:00:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 11 hours)     2018-09-30 07:00:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 12 hours)     2018-09-30 08:00:00
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 24 hours)     2018-09-30 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are only using tumbling window you can consider time as just another dimension and perform aggregations over this dimension and not use any windowing at all. 
Here is an example.
Let's consider the input stream schema is as the following:

`<sale_date BIGINT, region VARCHAR, total DOUBLE>`

Assuming the `sale_date` is the timestamp of the sale and our local time is PST, we can use the `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING` function to extract different time granularities for each sale for a given timezone as the following:

`CREATE STREAM foo AS SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(sale_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH', 'PST') AS sale_hour, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(sale_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'PST') AS sale_day, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(sale_date, 'yyyy-MM', 'PST') AS sale_month, region, total FROM orders;`

Now, you should be able to write your aggregate queries over this stream. For instance for daily sales for each region you can write the following query:

`CRAETE TABLE daily_sale AS SELECT sale_day, region, sum(total) FROM foo GROUP BY sale_day, region;`

Note that you don't need to specify a window for the above query.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp windows are always calculated relative to the epoch, which is UTC/GMT.

I can see the validity of wanting to aggregate by day based on your timezone. I've raised it as [an issue on the KSQL github project](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1968), and suggest you track it there.